# iOS UIScrollView Freehand drawings

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, uiscrollview, core-animation

I have an app with a scroll view that has a few layers. One of which is a draw layer that allows for a user to perform freehand drawing on it.

Drawing itself is very smooth and has not been a problem. However, when there are a lot of drawings on screen, things, such as scrolling and zooming in and out begin to lag quite a bit.

I know about reusing views when scrolling, but sometimes if a user say zooms out, many drawings can be on screen at the same time. I have tried a few different approaches such as using UIImageViews and CAShapeLayers for the drawings but the result is pretty much the same.

I know that this must be possible to do well because OneNote has this same functionality and performs like a champ.

Anyone have any ideas on how I can do this. Thanks!